# Angular js custom filter with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I want to use checkboxes with custom angularjs filter. Code that I'm using so far is on plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hoSaaim9sY8AOUd4inLJ

I have nested json array to store data. With angular forEach method I get an array of technologies and then flatten it and remove duplicate items to create an array called "techStack". Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('app', []);

function getUnique(inputArray){
            var outputArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
                if ((jQuery.inArray(inputArray[i], outputArray)) == -1){
                    outputArray.push(inputArray[i]);
                }
            }
            return outputArray;
        }

app.controller('CompaniesController', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('companies.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.companies = data;

        var techStackUnsorted = []
        var merged = [];
        $scope.techStack = [];

        angular.forEach(data, function(company, technologies) {
            var tech = company.technologies;
            techStackUnsorted.push(tech);
        })

        merged = getUnique(_.flatten(techStackUnsorted));
        $scope.techStack = merged;

    })
  }
]);
```

So, I need to filter companies with checkboxes by "technology"

I've read several solutions like this [Filter Array Using Checkboxes with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058284/filter-array-using-checkboxes-with-angularjs) or this [How to use checkbox to filter results with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509755/how-to-use-checkbox-to-filter-results-with-angular) but failed to make it work with my app as I'm using different arrays with ng-repeat. How can I make this work?

NOTE: seems like it doesn't load json in this plunkr, can't figure out why.

EDIT: forgot to add actual plunkr link, added it now